# Creación de columna con formato de fecha

Tags: r, date, datetime, time

Tengo una base de datos con información mensual desde agosto 2019 hasta septiembre 2019, en esta base tengo dos columnas, una de mes y otra de año, en la de mes tengo los 12 meses con el siguiente formato (Ene, Feb, Mar, Abr, May, Jun, Jul, Ago, Sep, Oct, Nov y Dic) en la columna de año, tengo (2017, 2018 y 2019), ¿cómo puedo generar una nueva columna que me de el formato de fecha por ejemplo 01/01/2018?

Tengo algunos ejemplos en las siguientes lineas de código, pero al momento de correr me saca puros `NA`:

```
consolidado2$Fecha <- format(as.Date(consolidado2$Fecha,"%Y-%m-%d"))

consolidado2$fecha <- as.POSIXct(paste0(consolidado2$Mes, " ", consolidado2$Año), format = "%Y-%m-%d", tz = "UTC")

consolidado2$fecha <- strptime(paste0(consolidado2$Mes, consolidado2$Año), format = "%Y-%m-%d", tz = "UTC")
```

Comment: Que gestor usas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que tienes algo como esto:

```
meses <- c('Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic') 

set.seed(2019)
consolidado2 <- data.frame(Año = sample(2010:2019, 100, replace=TRUE),
                           Mes = sample(meses, 100, replace = TRUE),
                           stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

head(consolidado2)

   Año Mes
1 2017 Jun
2 2017 Oct
3 2013 May
4 2016 Nov
5 2010 May
6 2010 Ago
```

El truco es conseguir un número de mes a partir de los nombres de los meses, algo que es sencillo si armas previamente un vector ordenado con los nombres de cada mes y usamos la función `match()`:

```
meses <- c('Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic') 
match(consolidado2$Mes, meses)

 [1]  6 10  5 11  5  8  3  7  3  1  4 12  3  7 10 12  7  5 10  1  2
 [22] 12  3  1  9 11 12 11  3  3  2  2  5  5  5  4  9  6  5  5  9  3
 [43]  9  9  5  9 11  5 12  3  7  1  3  5  6  5  9 11  6  8  2  8  6
 [64]  6 11  8  6  5  4  6  4  7  5 11  6  8  5  5 11  3  9  9  4  7
 [85]  3  4  5  4  5  7  6 11  7  7  3  9  4  8  4  3
```

Teniendo el número de mes, simplemente formateamos la cadena más o menos de la forma en que lo estabas haciendo (hay que agregar el día `01`):

```
strptime(
  paste0(consolidado2$Año, "-", match(consolidado2$Mes, meses), "-", '01'),
  format = "%Y-%m-%d", tz = "UTC"
)
```

Comment: Master, Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, me funciono perfecto. Saludos